# clock() fuction not working as expected with sorting functions

Tags: c, clock

I am trying to write a program that compares the time taken by quick sort and insertion sort functions, depending on the amount of elements in the array. This is the code i have come up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


//prototypes of insertion sort and quick sort
int * naive_sort(int * );
void smarter_sort(int * sorted, int left, int right);

int main(void)
{
    int size;

    long naiveTime, smarterTime;
    clock_t time1, time2, time3, time4;
    //creating an array of all the array sizes to be tested
    int arraySizes[5] = {10, 100, 1000, 5000, 10000};
    //loop to go through all the array sizes in arraySize
    for(int z = 0; z<5; z++)
    {
        size = arraySizes[z];
        int unsorted[size];
        int * sortedNaive;
        int * sortedSmarter;

        //filling unsorted array with random variables
        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
            unsorted[i] = rand() %100000;


        time3 = clock();
        //call quick sort
        sortedSmarter = unsorted;
        smarter_sort(sortedSmarter, 0, size-1);
        time4 = clock();

        time1 = clock();
        //call insertion sort
        sortedNaive = naive_sort(unsorted);
        time2 = clock();




        naiveTime = (time2-time1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        smarterTime = (time4 - time3)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        printf("Time taken for insertion sort with %d elements: %e \n", arraySizes[z], naiveTime);
        printf("Time taken for quick sort with %d elements:     %e \n", arraySizes[z], smarterTime);

}
    return 0;
}

//insertion sort function
int * naive_sort(int * sort)
{
    int i,j, temp; //pointer variables

    int size = sizeof(sort);
    for(i = 1; i<size; i++)
    {
        j = i-1;

        while(sort[i] < sort[j] && i>0)
        {
            temp = sort[j];
            sort[j] = sort[i];
            sort[i] = temp;
            j--;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return sort;
}



//quicksort
void smarter_sort(int * sorted, int left, int right)
{
    //left has the lowest index of the array to be sorted
    //right has the highest index of the array to be sorted

    int  p ;  //pivot
    int temp; //temporary
    int i ;
    int j ;

    if(left<right)      //function will stop sorting when lowest index         passes highest index
    {
        p = left;       //pivot is set to leftmost element
        i = left;       //i is set to leftmost element
        j = right;      //j is set to rightmost element

        while(i < j)        //stops sorting when left pointer passes right pointer
        {
            while(sorted[i]<=sorted[p] && i < right)    //increments left pointer until it is greater than pivot
                i++;
            while(sorted[j] > sorted[p])                //decrements right pointer until it is smaller than pivot
                j--;
            if(i<j)                                    //swap occurs only when left pointer is lower than right pointer
            {
                //swap i and j
                temp = sorted[i];
                sorted[i] = sorted[j];
                sorted[j] = temp;
            }

        }

        temp = sorted[p];           //swaps pivot and right pointer
        sorted[p]=sorted[j];
        sorted[j]=temp;
        smarter_sort(sorted,left,j-1);  //recursive call of sorting function on left side of pivot
        smarter_sort(sorted,j+1,right); //recursive call of sorting function on right side of pivot

    }
}
```

When run, the output states that the sorts took ~8.7e-313 seconds, which is way too small
Any ideas o what may be going wrong

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer now, but I might also note it appears you're calling both sorts on the same array, meaning your insertion sort is operating on an already sorted array

Answer (score 1):

You try to print `naiveTime` and `smarterTime` (variables of type `long`) with the `%e` formatting specifier which expects an argument of type `double`. this is undefined behaviour and results in the bogus output you observe. To fix this problem, make these two variables have type `double` and change the computation to:

```
    naiveTime = (time2-time1)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    smarterTime = (time4 - time3)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

so the division is actually done as a floating point division instead of an integer division.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `time1` and `time2` are of type `clock_t` which are not required to be floating point types. Indeed, on my system, `clock_t` is an `int32_t`.